# Purpose of AXVLC.VLCPlaylistMode enum

Tags: c#, vlc, libvlc

I am working in VLC ActiveX plugin in Windows form application. I am using addTarget method to load RTSP stream. There are four parameters(uri, options, playListMode, offset). 
I am passing the URI of a file first time which it plays perfectly well. I want to update the URI to point to another file I am unable to do it by again calling same addTarget method with path of new file.

I have 2 questions.

- How to update target URI in VLC ActiveX
- What is the purpose of each PlaylistMode enum value.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the URI updation issue by calling a method before adding target.

```
axVLCPlugin.playlistClear();
```

Then you can use **AXVLC.VLCPlaylistMode.VLCPlayListReplaceAndGo** in mode property. i.e third parameter of addTarget.